# How to let my checkbox animation finish before launching its Onclick method

Tags: java, android

I have created a Checkbox that triggers a method when clicked in my xml file

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/checkView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/linearLay"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLay"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLay"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLay"
android:onClick="delete"/>
```

the problem I have is that it instantly runs my (delete) method when clicked and doesn't let the checkbox animation finish, how do I fix this?

Comment: in onclick add a delay of 1 sec before performing delete operation

Answer (score 0):

Use animation listener, ex:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

 @Override
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
 boolean isChecked) {

     if(isChecked)
     {
         Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.car_filter_enter);
         animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                       //TODO: do your task
                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                  }
              });
        }
        checkbox1.startAnimation(animation); 
 }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the job after the delay

```
long delayMillis = 1000;    

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //this your code
        }
    },delayMillis);
```

1000 millisecond = 1 second

Your code will run after time